# Optional instance of a class

Tags: c++, oop

Hi I am trying to do something like the follow.

If have some variables passed from cmd line i.e..

```
 const char * outputtype1
 const char * outputtype2
```

The latter to can be NULL.

I then want to create an instance of a class if outputtype2 is set in command line. How can I have the instance of this class optional. i.e..

```
 if(outputtype2)
 {
 cats thomas(outputtype2);
 }
```

I then use this later like

```
thomas.eatfood(whiskers);
```

This is where it gets upset.Obviously thomas doesnt exist if outputtype2 is null, but why cant I just do this?

```
 if (outputtype2) 
 {
 cats thomas(outputtype2);
 }
```

without error
'thomas' was not declared in this scope. I fear I am missing some fundamental rule here.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Declare `cats thomas` outside the `if` scope.

Comment: only create and use thomas if there is an argument in outputtype2.

Comment: because it's about the existence of the object (regardless of initialisation) in programme memory. Your outputtype2 actually exist. but It is nulled. Usually when you use pointer you initialise to a valid location, not NULL. That's why people usually use `if(myptr == NULL)` check to control flow. It's not about `why can't I` - more like `How can I do this differently?`

Comment: @barak manos the if statement is my poor attempt to handle the fact outputtype2 can be NULL. I only want to create thomas if it has value. But because I use a method of the instance thomas later in the code, I get thomas is out of scope.

Comment: @user3512203 No, I asked what are you *really* trying to do. This is what you think the appropriate solution to your real problem is but it probably isn't. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Then declare `cats* thomas` outside the scope of the `if`, and allocate it dynamically inside it: `thomas = new cats(outputtype2)`.

Comment: @barak ew no don't do that. manual memory management what. it's 2014 dude

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: your comment is unclear dude (especially the part with the "what").

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't see how it's unclear. Manual memory management: no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, the problem is that you create the instance of the class in the if scope. Later you try to call the method eatfood of the object thomas but the object doesn't exist in the current scope.

Maybe you want to do this...

```
if (outputtype2) {
  cats thomas(outputtype1);
  thomas.eatfood(whiskers);
}
```

Or use a pointer...

```
Cats* thomas = NULL;

if (outputtype2) {
  thomas = new Cats(outputtype1);
}

if (thomas != NULL) {
  thomas->eatfood(whiskers);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution (null pointer) could you explain the line: thomas = new(outputtype1); Wouldn't it need a type specifier

Answer (score 5):

You'd probably want `boost::optional<cats>`. This allows you to define `thomas` up front, and assign `cats(outputtype2)` to thomas if and only if it's available.

The consequence is that on any use of `thomas`, you will have to check it was actually assigned to.

Comment: @NeilKirk: You've got sufficient rep, and on SO you don't need to ask for permission to fix those things.

Comment: I preferring assing cats, myself.

Answer (score 0):

What you miss is the concept of variable scope and visibility.
When you write :

```
if(outputtype2)
 {
 cats thomas(outputtype2);
 }
```

that means that the variable `thomas` exists only in the block it is declared in. Outside it, thomas doesn't exists anymore, both the object and the reference are destroyed when the control leaves the block. So you cant use them outside!

Find another logic to write your program.

Comment: He's asking what that logic would be.